# Possible: Insert my own HTML(whole website) into an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have all a websites HTML stored in a javascript string & I want to place it inside an iframe. **How can I place that HTML string into the iframe & make it show the website? I have tried this.src = HTML_STR; this.innerHTML = HTML_STR; but they dont show the HTML_STR.**

I understand that this maybe silly because instead of having the websites HTML in a string I could just set the iframes src to the website & show the website that way.

**BUT** the reason I am doing this is because its a website updater. So I want to get the website (that I am updating) HTML, convert all the elements with the class "updatable" to textareas(so they can be updated) then show that HTML in the iframe.

*The other reason for using an iframe & not just chucking the HTML in a div, is because each website imports a .css style sheet & I dont want their css file to affect my updater websites css or have my updater .css affect the websites HTML look thus if I show the website in an iframe each websites css wont affect each other.*

For example if updater.css has the following it will affect all the p elements in the other websites html:

```
p { background-color: red; width: 50%; }
```

So is there a way to insert my own HTML into an iframe. Or is there another way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: You can still avoid using an iframe by modifying the CSS of the users website.

So if your div has an id="webedit"
You just append that ID in front of all of the CSS for the customer's website

Comment: Yeah but that involves parsing css, compensating for badly formed css code & altering css code, thats a huge headache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to write to the iframe from the parent, you could do this:

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('myFrame');
ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
ifrm.document.open();
ifrm.document.write('Hello World!');
ifrm.document.close();
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/h2aRp/). Original code taken from [here](http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/) and [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1021687).

Comment: Thats so cool :). Thanks for the code. I'm amazed at all the stuff you can do with just html & javascript. If anyone's wondering, its important not to set the iframes src param otherwise u get security errors stopping u from accessing the document

Answer (score -2):

You could try doing `document.write(yourHTMLString);` inside the iframe.

Another way could be that you just use JavaScript to replace your updatable elements with textareas inside the original HTML when a certain button is clicked.

Comment: You can't just call `document.write()` on an iframe.