# Displaying another website in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

When I use an iframe it is not displaying. Does anyone know an alternative way to display other website on my webpage, using either iframe or div. (Or simple JavaScript, that would be really great.)

I have tried an iframe: Doesn't work

I tried `location.reference`: Doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: why iframe didn't works??any reason...????

Comment: Check this: [Iframe via JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528504/possible-insert-my-own-htmlwhole-website-into-an-iframe)

Comment: @Jan Hančič  very simple code like this...<iframe src="stackoverflow.com"  width="500" height="500">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

Comment: i think it is blocked.. thats why not working..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a simple `<iframe>` isn't working then there isn't any way of doing it in Javascript either. The most likely reason for the iframe not working is because the target site is sending a header to prevent other sites iframing it:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

A lot of sites will do this to prevent a common vulnerability known as [UI Redressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) or [Clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking). Some sites will also include some frame busting Javascript as a backup security measure to the HTTP header.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options):

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>` or `<iframe>`. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.

Comment: Thank you very much @MrCode
.. you said it correct.. i was looking for alternative to this..or some hack to get it work even if it is blocked at server ...

Comment: @monamona no problem :) unfortunately there's no way around this if the site is blocking it.

Comment: @SmartDev  In this kind of situations, you can use your server-side language (PHP, ASP.NET or other). For example; create a php page that receives the url as parameter. In this php page, fetch the content of the target website's page. Put the domain name to the beginning of all media items (images, css, js ...) And call your php page in the iframe. This will always work if the target website didn't prevent fetching page contents.

Comment: It depends on the website... sometimes file_get_contents() in PHP works.

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe isn't working then there could be two reason one in your coding and the target site preventing other sites iframing it. And somebody has mentioned the code try that out.

Answer (score -4):

If you need to do this with javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function populateIframe() {
            var ifrm = document.getElementById('myIframe');
            ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
            ifrm.document.open();
            ifrm.document.write('Hello World!');
            ifrm.document.close();
        }
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="populateIframe();">
    <iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the other "website" meaning URL ?